# rank of an expected value of a matrix

Tags: expected-value, matrix, ranks, vector

x is (a * 1) vector
y is (b * 1) vector
x and y are independent
then what is rank(E[xy'])
I know that xy' should be (a*b) matrix and since they are independent.
, however I am not sure about the rank

Comment: It depends partly on how many distinct values each of $X$ and $Y$ can take on: there isn't a universal answer.